# GoDaddy Domain only works with naked URL

Tags: url, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I have a static website hosted on Amazon S3 that I want to map to my GoDaddy Domain. My problem is example.com works but www.example.com doesn't (opposite naked url problem). The steps that I did:

1. Put website files in example.com s3 bucket.
2. Set bucket to act as static website and proper permissions.
3. Create www.example.com bucket that redirects to example.com
4. Using GoDaddy DNS Zone File: create CNAME www that points to example.com bucket

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create bucket example.com and configure S3 for static web hosting
2. Create bucket www.example.com and configure S3 to redirect all traffic to example.com
3. Configure your DNS to have www.example.com as a CNAME to the S3 bucket (www.example.com) URL
4. Configure your DNS to have example.com as a CNAME to the S3 bucket (example.com) URL

I think you're missing 4/ above.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html for more details